# Can someone let me know the approach for Mega Menu implementation in wicket . I mean how i should design

Tags: jquery, wicket-1.5

For example the mega menu looks like as per below site example
http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/jkmegamenu.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You design your html/css without taking wicket into account and then (if necessary) add some wicket-id tags to your html tags. This is one of the strengths of wicket.